# Can a C# Safe Navigation Operator (?.) be used to check if Object is null, as well as property?

Tags: c#, syntax, null, safe-navigation-operator

This is mainly a syntactic sugar/best-practice question.

Here is a code example in question:

```
if (_instanceData?.DataSourceType != null && Util.IsEntityBacked(_instanceData.DataSourceType) {// code}
```

I understand that the safe navigation operator will continue execution if _instanceData is null, but in this case will the first boolean in the conditional be evaluated as expected?  Is this going to successfully null check on both _instanceData and DataSourceType?

Another Example:

```
if (LockAcquired && _instanceData?.ObjInfo != null) {// code}
```

In this case, it is possible that _instanceData is null, or it is not, but ObjInfo is null.  Is it better practice to just old-fashioned null check both object and property, or will this get the job done as expected?

edit: The question is better described as:
Is `if (obj?.prop != null)` equivalent to
 `if (obj != null && obj.prop != null)`

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking - but in the first example, if either `_instanceData` or `_instanceData.DataSourceType` is null, then the result of `_instanceData?.DataSourceType` will be null, so the first operand of the `&&` operator will be evaluate to false, so the second operand won't be evaluated.

Comment: If that isn't enough information, I suggest you try to put together a [mcve] - which I suspect will answer your question anyway, just by running it.

Comment: Your above code snippets are valid and is the expected use case.

Comment: `?.` isn't doing anything at all to `DataSourceType`. Your `!= null` check is doing that. but like others have said, it's not clear what you're actually asking.

Comment: You seem to see a difference between an object and a property ? There isn't any, the ?.Operator can be applied to objects or structs, not matter where they come from, also from properties. "Save navigation" is a curious title for the operator.
It just saves you to writte if (x!=null && x.y != null && x.y.z!=null) to if (x?.y?.z != null). It means `If  value is already null the result of the expression is null, otherwise  take the value of the following member`.

Comment: The name `safe navigation` comes from the fact that you can navigate to nested properties safely without exception if somewhere along the tree resolves to null. The name comes from the fact that it saves you layering `if` blocks to get to some inner property. It saves a bit of space for conditional expressions like this scenario but it can save dozens of lines when just accessing a property far down an object tree.

Comment: @Jake you can check what IL converts your code into from here https://sharplab.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is equivalent to

```
if (_instanceData != null && _instanceData.DataSourceType != null && Util.IsEntityBacked(_instanceData.DataSourceType) {// code}
```

The second is equivalent to

```
if (LockAcquired && _instanceData != null && _instanceData.ObjInfo != null) {// code}
```

So it will check if _instanceData is null, then check if _instanceData.DataSourceType is null, then the last condition. As you said, this is just syntactical sugar so you don't have to write two `!= null` conditions. The IL code that results is exactly the same, so its a matter of preference whether or not to use the operator.

It does save a TON of space when accessing deeply nested properties, which is where its most useful

```
if(Parent != null)
{
    if(Parent.Child != null)
    {
        if(Parent.Child.GrandChild != null)
        {
             Parent.Child.GrandChild.GreatGrandChild.name = "Parent IV";
        }
     }
}
```

becomes

```
Parent?.Child?.GrandChild?.GreatGrandChild.name = "Parent IV";
```

Saves a lot of space! Even if you collapsed all the ifs into one statement it still saves loads of keystrokes and screen noise.